# Give an example of a divergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum a_{3n}$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Give an example of a divergent series $\sum a_n$ such that $\sum a_{3n}$ is convergent.

I am not able to find such example. Please help.

Comment: Can you solve this with $2n $ instead of  $3n $?

Comment: I suspect there may be some typos in your question, but as written you could just take $a_n=0$ for all $n$...

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Yes $\sum(-1)^n/n^2$ is that.

Comment: I also doubt what you wrote is what you meant to write.

Comment: Probably you want a convergent series such that the subseries you mentioned *diverges*.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Edited. Please see

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo What will be the series ∑an such that it  is convergent but ∑$a_{3n}$ is divergent, about which you have talked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$a_n=\sin(\frac{n\pi}3)$$

Clearly, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ is analogous to $1-1+1-1+1-\cdots$ which does not converge but
$$a_{3n}=0$$ for all $n$ and $$\sum 0=0$$ (or rigorously the sequence of partial sum is a sequence of zeroes, thus the limit of the infinite sum is zero).